# Why do i need to Initiate the DBContext object inside the Controller class constructor & inside the Repository class constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am reading the following tutorial about asp.net mvc + Entity framework:-

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

and i find that the author is initiating the DbContext object inside the repository class's constructor as follow:-

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private SchoolContext context;

        public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }
```

and also the author will be initiating the DBContext object inside the Controller class constructor as follow:-

```
 public class StudentController : Controller
   {
      private IStudentRepository studentRepository;

      public StudentController()
      {
         this.studentRepository = new StudentRepository(new SchoolContext());
      }

      public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
      {
         this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
      }

      //
```

**First Question**.  can anyone advice what is the purpose of initiating the DBContext object inside the Repository & Controller classes Constructor ? i mean i can replace the repository to be as follow:-

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private SchoolContext context = new SchcooleContext
//No need for this constructor !!!
      //  public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
     //   {
     //       this.context = context;
      //  }
```

and keep the controller class as is ...

**second question** . do i need to explicitly mention that the repository implements the IDisposable as follow:-

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
```

now if i remove IDisposable the code should work well.. so what is the purpose of explicitly implementing the IDisposable inside the Repository class ? i mean since i will be calling the StudentRepository.Dispose() method from the Controller class itself,, and the base Controller class by default implement the Idisposable object.. so is there any valid reason to explicitly implement the IDisposable object inside the StudentRepository ?

Comment: I think the `SchoolContext` is meant to be instantiated only once per request and shared with other repositories within the controller.

Comment: @Hendry so what is the relation between doing so and using the same context across multiple repos can you adivce more please ?

Comment: If you haven't already, might pay to do some research into `Dependency Injection`, then the code in the example might make more sense. Implementing `IDisposable` is arguable, depends on how purist you want to get, but generally speaking, if you have a dependency (i.e. DBContext, File etc) which implements `IDisposable` it's a good idea to do the same, and dispose of those dependencies correctly.

Comment: @johnG: right from the link of the tutorial, the author wrote "You could instantiate a new context in the repository, but then if you used multiple repositories in one controller, each would end up with a separate context. Later you'll use multiple repositories in the Course controller, and you'll see how a unit of work class can ensure that all repositories use the same context."

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> can anyone advice what is the purpose of initiating the DBContext
>   object inside the Repository & Controller classes Constructor ?

The practice of passing in dependencies in the constructor to the classes that need them is called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It is generally considered good practice and has great advantages.

Actually, he is not! If you notice, the `StudentRepository` just accepts a `SchoolContext`. It never instantiates anything. That means that `StudentRepository` is happy taking any class that derives from `SchoolContext` and it can do its work. A common use case is, in production you will pass it the real thing, in testing you may pass it a `Mock SchoolContext` which never saves to the database but maybe just an in memory list.

You'll notice in `StudentController` he has 1 constructor which takes an `IStudentRepository`. This follows the same as above. Any ol' `IStudentRepository` will do. However, you also notice a constructor which instantiates both classes `new StudentRepository(new SchoolContext());`. This is actually referred to as `Poor Mans Dependency Injection`. It's a shortcut. In the real world you would typically see something in some startup config file that says: When a class needs an `IStudentRepository` give it `new StudentRepository(new SchoolContext())`.

> do i need to explicitly mention that the repository implements the
>   IDisposable as follow:-

[IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Yes. `DbContext` implements `IDisposable`, and so anything that wraps it should as well. The idea is that when you are done with `DbConext` it needs to be closed. `IDisposable` communicates that. It is typically used for "unmanaged resources" such as files and connections that need to be "released".

Comment: i know that dispose will released any unmanaged resources... but my question is why the author is explicitly implementing the IDisposable , as follow:-

"public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable"

now if i remove the IDisposable and have the class as follow:-

"public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository"

will it make any differences ?

Comment: If you remove IDisposable, it will still work. But now you are in danger of leaving open connections all over the place because no one knows they need to be disposed.

Comment: so i need to explicitly implement the IDisposable interface , to make sure users will provide a Dispose method inside the repository ..and if they do not do so they will get a compilation error...is this correct ? but explicitly implementing the IDisposable will not have any impact ..

Comment: Users don't provide a Dispose method, the programmer does. I'm sorry, I don't really understand your comment. If it's simply about IDisposable you may want to ask a different question.

Comment: i mean i need to explicitly implement the IDisposable to make sure Programmer will implement the Dispose() method,,,

Comment: Now it seems like the question is about Interfaces in general. Yes, an Interface requires the implementing class to implement everything in it.

Comment: i am not asking about interfaces,, my question is mainly why the author explicitly uses IDisposable ,,, what i understand from your reply that he did so it make sure any programmer will provide an implementation for the Dispose method ? is this correct?

Comment: The author is the programmer right? He implements `IDisposable` so that when he is using his repository he knows it must be disposed. `IDisposable` will allow him to call `.Dispose()`, wrap it in a `using`, or in some frameworks they will dispose all `IDisposable` for you. No different to why you would implement `ISerializable` or any other `interface`..